# Stop InstallShield installation when Inno Setup is detected

Tags: inno-setup, installshield

I am trying to migrate from InstallShield to Inno Setup. I have all setup but I got stuck on a single case when the user might downgrade from Inno Setup back to the InstallShield. I need InstallShield to fail the installation or at least warn the user to uninstall Inno Setup version first manually (otherwise I get two versions installed and things get messed up).

I CAN´T of course change the existing InstallShield installers in any way since they have already been released. Solution must come from Inno Setup. Any ideas how this could be done? I understand this might me impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I solved it. (kind of)

There is a simple trick what you can do to trick the InstallShield to think it is already installed even if it is not.

First you need to locate all the registry entries with your UpgradeCode and ProductCode (it should be 3 entries for the UC and 5 for the PC) normally created by the InstallShield. Also note that both GUIDS are stored in the registry in reversed form (first 8 chars are backwards!!! - rest I am not sure of but it can be googled).

Now you need to make the InnoSetup recreate this registry entries. When InstallShield starts it looks for existing version in the registry, if it finds one it tries to uninstall it using the copy of the original installer - path to the copy is stored in the registry at

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products{reversed guid of product code}\InstallProperties]

"LocalPackage"="C:\Windows\Installer\[random string].msi"

If InstallShield wont find this file it will fail. You can also create your own MSI file which will call the uninstall.exe file from InnoSetup.

Comment: This is a VERY BAD thing to do and will result in a corrupt Windows Installer service.  These registry entries are owned by the installer and you should not be manipulating them in this way.

Answer (score 0):

A stock InstallShield template automatically authors a prevent downgrade rule into the MSI.  Assuming your InnoSetup project was created using the same UpgradeCode as the InstallShield project this should work automatically.

If you gave your new InnoSetup project a new UpgradeCode GUID and authored a remove legacy product type rule using the old GUI in the Upgrade table there really isn't much InstallShield could possibly do.   That's the nature of installers...  once it's shipped it's shipped.

Comment: Inno Setup does not use Windows Installer/MSI, so any GUIDs are irrelevant here.

Comment: Ah in that case all is lost.

Comment: Yes InnoSetup is creating .exe and does not use Upgrade Code

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this can be done. The Inno Setup does not use the Windows Installer, so the InstallShield won't even know that your product is already installed. And Inno Setup uninstaller cannot know that the InstallShield installer is starting.

The best what you can do is to have your Inno Setup installer remove the InstallShield installation and install itself to another folder. So when you re-install the InstallShield installation, it at least won't conflict/break the Inno Setup installation. And user will be able to correctly uninstall the new Inno Setup installation, if needed.

Comment: Crazy thought... have a fake MSI that doesn't show up in Add/Remove Programs that has the UpgradeCode of the old InstallShield installer.  Then have innosetup install this silently and uninstall it silently  just to be a blocking marker for the old MSI.  That should work.  That said, it's not something I would do....

Comment: 1) By "uninstall silently", so you mean "uninstall by the Inno Setup uninstaller"? 2) So the fake MSI would look like a new version of the old MSI?

Comment: Yup, that's the idea. Kind of a new twist on the idea of a Trojan MSI...

Comment: I am not having a problem with upgrade to InnoSetup... I am checking the registry for the certain upgrade code (you can also run the uninstall string which can be found in the registry to force uninstall of the current InstallShield) the problem is just with downgrade to the original InstallShield

Comment: @Safiron What do you react to? To my answer or to the comment by @ChristopherPainter? I do not see a relation to either.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl To your original post, I might have understant it wrong... My idea is when installing InnoSetup write in the registry key structure that is created by InstallShield during the installation... this might cause InstallShield to think that another version of this product is installed.

Comment: That's basically what @ChristopherPainter suggested, just using a stub (sub)installer. I believe that Windows Installer uses some database, not just registry. Replicating the database in Inno Setup would probably be complicated and error-prone.